# Javascript only show elements when class XY is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first post here.

i have a big problem. i am in a bootcamp, currently.
I have a site and sections

```js
const bookmarkButton = document.querySelectorAll('.pictureBook')
bookmarkButton.forEach(function (setIt) {
  setIt.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setIt.classList.toggle('bookmarkChecked')
  })
})
```

```css
.pictureBook {
  all: unset;
  background-image: url(/img/bookmark-svgrepo-com.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.bookmarkChecked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <section class="main__section">
    <h2 class="question__title">Frage</h2>
    <p class="question__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla eius
      voluptatibus modi voluptates nisi quam expedita fugiat repudiandae
      animi ab.
    </p>
    <button class="pictureBook"></button>
    <button class="showanswer__btn">Antwort anzeigen</button>
    <p class="answershowed hideanswer">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A nemo
      libero tempore dolore numquam dolorum sed cumque nihil explicabo
      ullam.
    </p>
  </section>
```

Now i can click the bookmark "svg" and opacity gone to 100 % ( bookmark set, color black )

I have a button. and i want, only show the "classes" i added the class for bookmarked it.
I am on the Limit. Google doesn`t help.  Maybe you can?

When i click another button in my footer, the site Show please only the active sections with the class bookmarkChecked.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Great question. Can you please add url to the svg image, or some similar svg, so we can see the "picture book" button?

Comment: @VlastimilLisák Just use this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Book_only.jpg

Comment: If I'm getting it right. Can you please specify which elements (with which classes) you want to show if what button is clicked? The bookmark button?

Comment: I have button in the footer-section.this section , the idea, only show the bookmarked section. all other elements would be "hide" ( display:none ) The bookmark-button only change the color (opacity) of the svg-file.

Comment: @Malte1983 But in your code (in your question) isn't footer section. Can you please add this code, so it is complete?

Comment: Hi, your question not clear.

Comment: The pictureBook button is not visible in the snippet due to all:unset
But I think it's irrelevant to the question any as it seems to be about hiding the sections.

Answer (score 0):

A bookmarked button has the bookmarkChecked class. So you can use
`querySelectorAll` to choose only the bookmarked button.

1. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to loop over the list of buttons.
2. Inside the `forEach` callback get the corresponding section for each button using the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method
3. Now you can hide the bookmarked section using a class to set display none.
4. If all this needs to happen after a button click, then do the following inside an `addEventListener`.